# C++ Program Finding Prime Numbers and Timing itself

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a c++ program that finds n prime numbers and times itself. I have already done this in 5 other languages using this logic. For some reason, this code does nothing. I am using the Code Blocks compiler. What causes this code not to work and how can I fix it? I am not very familiar with c++ so it will probably be something trivial.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int n=10;
    int b=new int[n];
    int c=0;
    int d=2;
    while(c<n){
        bool e=true;
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
            if(d<sqrt(b[i])){
                break;
            }
            if(d%b[i]==0){
                e=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(e){
            b[c]=d;
            c++;
        }
        d++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
        cout << b[i]+"\n" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `int b=new int[n];` a typo? It should not compile, you are assigning a pointer to an `integer`. Also, you have `while(c<n){` but you do not update `c` so this is an infinite loop.

Comment: Please give your variables meaningful names. This is annoying to read.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the compiler error message or what goes wrong when you run it.

Comment: Your not changing c or n inside the while loop so it is an infinite loop

Comment: @Shafik Well, I'm not sure. I do not have the actual code that I used. I have the code I used for php and copied it statement by statement. The code that I ran compiled correctly, but did not do anything. It was probably an infinite loop.

Comment: When I run it, nothing happens (infinite loop?)

Comment: I don't know about the other 5 languages you used, but C++ allows more than 1 character for variable identifiers.

Comment: Note that `if(d<sqrt(b[i]))` is pointless, `d` is always larger than any prime found so far, you meant to break `if (d < b[i]*b[i])` or `if (sqrt(d) < b[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

```
int b=new int[n];
   //^^compile error
```

should be

```
int* b=new int[n];  //also need initialize array b
```

Meanwhile:

```
if (d<sqrt(b[i]))
```

You should initialize `b` before you try to access it.

besides:

```
cout << b[i]+"\n" << endl;
```

**EDIT:** @Daniel Fischer, this would compile with `std::` added before `cout` and `endl`, but will result in undefined behavior.
try:

```
cout << b[i] << endl;
```

if you want to print `b[i]`s only.

Additionally, inside your `while` loop, you need to increment `c` after `b[c] = d`, otherwise, it is going to the element into the same index again and again.

Comment: This is not the exact code I compiled. The error is logical, not gramatical.

Comment: @Bob If you already made the logic to work in other languages, then it should also work in C++ if you follow it strictly. I have listed one logic error inside the `additionally` part.

Comment: The `if (d<sqrt(b[i]))` is pointless, but not a problem, whenever that condition is evaluated, `b[i]` has already been filled with a prime. `cout << b[i]+"\n" << endl;` compiles (after using `std::` on `cout` and `endl`), but invokes undefined behaviour when run, since that sends `&("\n"[b[i]])` to `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

`int b` should be declared as `int *b`

You need to add `using namespace std` if you want to use `cout` etc. without namespace prefixes.
With prefixes you can do std::cout.

Also you've got an infinite loop because c is never incremented.